# Filter a elequent relationship by date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

-- Laravel 8.* --

Hi, i am trying to respond, in a api, data about football, domain.test/api/fixtures/2020-11-06 should be giving a array of leagues with fixtures for the date given.

At this point I have App\Models\League with a a filter for fixtures hasMany.

```
/**
 * Get all the fixtures from this league
 */
public function fixtures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Fixture', 'league_id', 'id');
}
```

And in the FixturesController I call it with a whereHas:

```
$leagues = League::with('fixtures')->whereHas('fixtures', function($q) use ($date) { $q->where('date', $date); })->get();


return $this->responseWithSuccess(['leagues' => $leagues ]);
```

But this is returning the wrong answer.

```
"leagues": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "...",
            "name": "Premier League",
            "fixtures": [
                {
                    "id": 62,
                    "...",
                    "date": "2020-10-17",
```

Help Please!
What am I doing wrong?
And Can somebody tell me the best way to debug errors like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the same function you have on the `whereHas` method to the `with` method.

In the way you're doing it, the `whereHas` is going to filter the Leagues that have a Fixture on that date, but the `with` is going to bring you all the Fixtures of each of those Leagues, not just those on the given date.

Another thing, for dates preferably use `whereDate` instead of just where.

That said, your query could look like this:

```
League::with(['fixtures' => function($q) use ($date) { 
        $q->whereDate('date', $date); 
    }])
    ->whereHas('fixtures', function($q) use ($date) { 
        $q->whereDate('date', $date); 
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Does 'with' take a second parameter? In my version it gives me  a error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You have to pass it as an array [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). I updated the answer

Comment: Perfect work like a charm, can you explain why is the "whereHas"  needed when "with" is already filtering the data. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: The `whereHas` will filter the League models that have fixtures on that date (it will not bring the Leagues that does not have fixtures that do not meet the condition). If you used only the `with`, it would return all the Leagues, but with a empty relation field for those that do not meet the condition.

Comment: You can debug your query dumpig it [DB Debugging](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#debugging) to see the difference on DB level.

Comment: Ok, got it! So if I want to filter between dates it would like something like this:
$leagues = League::with(['fixtures' => function($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->whereDate('date', '>=', $start)->whereDate('date', '<=', $end);
        }])->whereHas('fixtures', function($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->whereDate('date', '>=', $start)->whereDate('date', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->get();

Comment: Yep, that's the way